# How do I view and audit Dataflow actions like Create/Cancel Job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-logging

I'm using [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) with a project with many users, and would like to be able to understand when jobs are created and by whom.  Similarly, if a job is cancelled, I'd like to confirm the identity of the initiator of this action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Platform records these events in a per-service [audit log](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/), which is viewable both in the [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) UI as well as the Activity section.  To view an event in Activity, navigate to that page and view the relevant entry, as below:

[image: Activity UI]

To view an event in the Log Viewer, go to the Logging page and select '*Dataflow*' and '*activity*', which should filter results to the structured audit log entries.  This will contain more information than the Activity entry, and can be exported to [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) as well:

[image: Cloud Logging UI]